# Микроразметка на адрес и реквизиты фирмы

Tags: html, schema.org

Как можно сделать микроразметку на такой вот код для страницы контактов?

```
<h1>Контакты</h1>
<p>ООО Компания</p>
<p><a href="tel:88002000500">8 800 2000 500</a></p>
<p><a href="mailto:info@mail.com">info@mail.com</a></p>
<p>Москва, Ак.Королева, 32<br /> оф. 23</p>
<div>
    <p>ОГРН 1037700085444</p>
    <p>ИНН 7717107991</p>
    <p>КПП 771901001</p>
    <p>Юр адрес: 105318, Москва г, Ибрагимова ул,<br /> д. 31, офис 30Б</p>
    <p>р/с 40702810638040112712 в ПАО СБЕРБАНК Г. МОСКВА</p>
    <p>к/с 30101810400000000225.</p>
</div>
```

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Так. Только немного подредактировать код надо будет.

```
<iv itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <h1>Контакты</h1>
    <p itemprop="name">ООО Компания</p>
    <p><a href="tel:88002000500" itemprop="telephone">8 800 2000 500</a></p>
    <p><a href="mailto:info@mail.com" itemprop="email">info@mail.com</a></p>
    <p itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress"><span itemprop="addressLocality">Москва</span>, <span  itemprop="streetAddress">Ак.Королева, 32<br /> оф. 23</span></p>
    <div>
        <p>ОГРН 1037700085444</p>
        <p>ИНН 7717107991</p>
        <p>КПП 771901001</p>
        <p>Юр адрес: 105318, Москва г, Ибрагимова ул,<br /> д. 31, офис 30Б</p>
        <p>р/с 40702810638040112712 в ПАО СБЕРБАНК Г. МОСКВА</p>
        <p>к/с 30101810400000000225.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Реквизиты не размечаются.

Разметка валидна:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ!